# Could not resolve a service of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggingBuilder

Tags: nlog

I have followed the steps in the following website.

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3

However, when I run my project, the following error has been displayed.

System.Exception: 'Could not resolve a service of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggingBuilder' for the parameter 'logger' of method 'Configure' on type 'myProj.Startup'.'

The code stopped at the following point *throw*. . I have tried to google it but it seems that there is no similar issue. I wish someone could help. Thanks!

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
            try
            {
                logger.Debug("init main");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //NLog: catch setup errors
                logger.Error(exception, "Stopped program because of exception");
                *throw;*
            }
            finally
            {
```